# How can I draw two polygons in C

Tags: c

The string I gave contains the coordinates of two polygons, but my code only draws a single polygon. How should I edit my code so that it draws both polygons?

Because the coordinates of more than one polygon may be present in the string given to me.

How can I create a dynamic array of coordinates for a given random string?

```
int main()
{
    char metin[] = "2B(20,20)(30,20)(20,40)(10,40)(20,20)(40,22)(50,32)(30,32)(40,22)F";
    int koordinatlar[18];
    
    char *ptr = metin;
    int i = 0;
    
    while(*ptr != '\0')
    {
        if(*ptr == '(')
        {
            int x, y;
            if(sscanf(ptr, "(%d,%d)", &x, &y) == 2)
            {
                koordinatlar[i] = x *10 ;
                koordinatlar[i + 1] = y *10;
                i += 2;
            }
            
        }
        ptr++;
    }
    
    for(int a = 0; a < i; a++)
    {
        printf("%d ", koordinatlar[a]);
    }
    
    initwindow(500,500);
    
    setfillstyle(8,2);
    fillpoly(5, koordinatlar);
    getch();
    closegraph();
}   
...
```

Comment: Apparently something like `fillpoly(4, koordinatlar + 10);` should work.

Comment: @RichpooR What problems do you have when using KiraHoneybee's or my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if a point that you've extracted is the same as the starting point:

```c
if (sscanf(ptr, "(%d,%d)", &x, &y) == 2) {
    koordinatlar[i] = x * 10;
    koordinatlar[i + 1] = y * 10;

    if (i > 0 && koordinatlar[0] == koordinatlar[i] &&
                 koordinatlar[1] == koordinatlar[i + 1]) 
    {
        // endpoint found - draw polygon here - this is assuming
        // fillpoly wants the number of vertices + 1:
        fillpoly(i / 2 + 1, koordinatlar);
        i = 0; // and reset `i`
    } else {
        i += 2;
    }
}
```

For an arbitrary large array you could use `malloc` and `realloc` to expand the array dynamically.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n4b55haxE) (including `malloc`/`realloc`)

Comment: Would it make more sense if we count the "(" signs in the text in a separate function and open an array twice that number? @TedLyngmo

Comment: @RichpooR  That would certainly be possible but it's a matter of taste. In that case you would need to allocate memory for _all_ points in _all_ polygons instead of just enough memory for the polygon with the most number of points like I showed.

Comment: This seems a bit complicated to me, let me try to do it as I said to simplify it. @TedLyngmo

Comment: @RichpooR See it like this: If you have 100000000 polygons with 5 points in each, do you want to allocate memory for 500000000 points or 5 points? If you know beforehand that the total number of points will be low, then go ahead and allocate memory for all of them, otherwise, I'd go for not allocating more than what's needed.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it confused me later because I had to calculate the area of ​​these shapes and so on. @TedLyngmo

Comment: @RichpooR You can do that at the same place where you call `fillpoly` in my example.

Comment: I want to ask this "coordinates[i] = x * 10;
                coordinates[i + 1] = y * 10;" The reason why I multiply by 10 in this part of the code is that the resulting shape is large. How can I adjust its size without changing my coordinate values? @TedLyngmo

Comment: @RichpooR That's a totally different question, but you can scale it any way you want before painting it.

Comment: I couldn't see how I could scale it. Can you help me if you know? @TedLyngmo

Comment: You copy the array of points and multiply both axis in the copy with the scaling factor, then paint. It's no different from what you now do once when reading the points.

Answer (score -1):

> How can I create a dynamic array of coordinates for a given random string?

Here is a code that will produce a coodinate list in the same format that you are using it, but dynamically sized from the string (if you're willing to use std):

```
#include <vector>
int* GetCoodinatesFromString(char* theString, int &resultCount)
{
    std::vector<int> coordList;

    char *ptr = theString;

    while(*ptr != '\0')
    {
        if(*ptr == '(')
        {
            int x, y;
            if(sscanf(ptr, "(%d,%d)", &x, &y) == 2)
            {
                coordList.push_back(x *10);
                coordList.push_back(y *10);
            }

        }
        ptr++;
    }

    int* theResult=new int[coordList.size()];
    for (int i=0;i<coordList.size();i++) theResult[i]=coordList[i];
    resultCount=coordList[i];
    return theResult;
}
```

and now your function becomes:

```
int main()
{
    char metin[] = "2B(20,20)(30,20)(20,40)(10,40)(20,20)(40,22)(50,32)(30,32)(40,22)F";

    // Changed to make it dynamically allocate the size instead of it
    // being hard-coded to 18
    int resultCount;
    int *koordinatlar=GetCoordinatesFromString(metin,resultCount);
    
    for(int a = 0; a < resultCount; a++)
    {
        printf("%d ", koordinatlar[a]);
    }
    
    initwindow(500,500);
    
    setfillstyle(8,2);
    fillpoly(5, koordinatlar);
    getch();
    closegraph();

    delete [] koorinatlar;
}
```

So to draw two polygons split them into two strings, and call fillpoly on the results of both strings.

Edit: Here's a way to do it in pure C:

```
int* MagicMalloc(int* thePreviousList, int addThis, int* theListSize)
{
    int* theNewList;
    if (!thePreviousList) theNewList=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    else theNewList=(int*)realloc(thePreviousList,((*theListSize)+1)*sizeof(int));

    theNewList[*theListSize]=addThis;
    *theListSize=*theListSize+1;

    return theNewList;
}
```

Then GetCoordinatesFromString turns into this:

```
int* GetCoordinatesFromString(char* theString, int *resultCount)
{
    *resultCount=0;
    int* theResult=NULL;
    char *ptr = theString;
    while(*ptr != '\0')
    {
        if(*ptr == '(')
        {
            int x, y;
            if(sscanf(ptr, "(%d,%d)", &x, &y) == 2)
            {
                theResult=MagicMalloc(theResult,x*10,resultCount);
                theResult=MagicMalloc(theResult,y*10,resultCount);
                
                printf("WTF: %d\n",*resultCount);
            }
        }
        ptr++;
    }

    return theResult;
}
```

Note that this is pretty inefficient because it reallocates the memory every time you add a number to it.  But it'll work okay for small lists of things.  If you need to work with bigger lists, it'll require more logic and an extra variable to track the actual size of the array vs the count of items in it.

Comment: Is it possible to do it using malloc? @KiraHoneybee

Comment: @RichpooR Added an update with a pure-C solution

Comment: Removed references.  Damn, it's been a long time.